# What semantic notions underlie 'to see, show' and 'order'?

Tags: этимология

Please see the screenshot ([original](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/master/1091)) with my question inscribed:

[image]

Comment: please add a text summary of what you are asking about - images are not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Указ` is a type of a formal order

A real life example: when a master orders (`приказывает` or `даёт указание/приказ`) a servant or a slave to do something he might indicate that with a gesture of finger pointing (`указывает`) to the side as if **showing** (`показывает`) what he must do

A gesture of finger pointing can be interpreted as drawing someone's attention to the object being pointed at, and so **showing** them that object.

In Russian as in English `index finger` is `указательный палец`, because it's used for indicating/pointing at (`указывать`) things and as it were revealing them to others, or **showing**.

With regard to semantic link with **to see**, to me it seems rather weak. Other than the fact that `seeing` could result from `indicating/pointing at/showing` it could be said that the verb `видеться`, a cognate of `видеть`,  is a synonym of the verb `казаться`, itself a cognate of `указ`, and that another way of saying `по-каж-и!` (**show** me) might be `дай/позволь по-смотр-еть!` (let me **see**/let me have a **look**).

Answer (score 0):

The verb *ukazat* (*указать*, *указывать*) comes from the noun *указ* which means decree, ruling. This was typically used for decrees issued by Tsars. Thus, the original meaning of *указать* is to give **order**/direction to do something or to behave in a certain way. Nowadays this meaning is often used within family context, for example a teenage child fed up with parents' orders might say to them "кончайте мне указывать!" ("stop telling me what to do!").

Now, the more common meaning of *указать* is to show, demonstrate, point someone to something specific or some detail within a wider area, especially when that someone is seeking the detail. For example, the police may bring a robbery victim in front of several suspects and ask the victim to *указать* (**show**/point to) the one who robbed him. Or a criminal may, while interrogated, *указать* (**show**/reveal/disclose) his accomplices. Or one may *указать* the location of the treasure on the Treasure Island map.

The meaning of "to **see**" is no more relevant in this context than the fact that the person being showed something can / supposed to see it.